# Joining two tables on fields having different names but same meaning

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets, `df1` having columns

```
Date Name Text Label
     John        1
     Jack        0
     Jim         1
```

(I only filled those fields that I need)
and `df2` having columns

```
NickName   Label
John         1
John         1 
Wes          0
Jim          0
Jim          0
Jim          0
Martin       0
```

`Name` and `Nickname` indicate the same things: however some observations might be included in only one of the two columns. `Label` in `df1` is not the same of `Label` in `df2` (sad name choice), so I will need to rename `Label` in `df2`, for example with `Index`.
I would like to have in `df2` also the column `Label` (from `df1`) for those values (`Nickname`) that are in `df1` and, for those ones not in `df1`, the value -1.
The expected output should be

```
NickName   Label   Index
John         1      1 
John         1      1
Wes          0      -1
Jim          0      0
Jim          0      0
Jim          0      0
Martin       0      0
...
```

Please note that all Name in `df1` are in `df2`.
For renaming the column, I have no problem (using rename in pandas) but I would need actually to understand how to merge the two datasets in order to get the three columns and corresponding values as in the expected output. I am not familiar with merging/joining, but I would say that I would need something like

```
 df1.append(df2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and add `suffixes` to the columns so you can see which original DatFrame they came from.

```py
df1.merge(
    df2, 
    left_on='Name', 
    right_on='Nickname', 
    suffixes=('_left', '_right'), 
    how="outer",
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot Alex. So you  would suggest to rename Label in df2 in a different way before merging the two dataset, don't you?

Comment: No, the `suffixes` parameter will handle that for you

Comment: So to clear that up a little, `df1["Label"]` will be renamed `Label_left`.